# How to call Tier price field in custom admin form?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, forms, tierprice

In my custom Admin form I want to add the `tire price` field. How to achieve this? What needs to be use as render?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_price_tier` as *renderer*